# Webmin: Possible Disconnect due to Perl

Tags: media-server, perl

So, basically, after experimenting with making my Raspberry Pi a Minecraft server. I've thought about it and I also discovered I have a 1TB external USB hard-drive, and so I now I want to turn my RB-Pi into a file server so that way I no longer have to bring my hard drive with me. So I followed guides like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPGpMSFZc9A) and it took me a while to realize that once I depackaged Webmin I could immediately go to my private IP and configure/access my personal file server.

The trouble is, before-hand I tried using [this](https://www.pi-supply.com/make/build-your-own-cloud-storage-file-server-with-a-raspberry-pi/) guide first. Installing Apache, and then when I connected it brought me to Apache's page. So thinking that these programs were conflicting I uninstall Apache - reboot my RB-Pi - connect again and still nothing. I even used the right port 10000. There was a sign that it was working because it took time for the page to load to show nothing. Whereas if both services are stopped it just immediately says "Failed to connect."

Ignoring all these details, I go check the service of Webmin and it gives me this message.[image]

Now I check perl's status:[image]

I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the perl service. I do remember installing this service before with other projects.

So with all that information. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html) is a programming language and associated interpreter.  `Webmin` happens to be written in `perl`.  The `authentication error` probably has to do with your file permissions when you setup `webmin`

It's probably a good idea to stick with `owncloud` which is far simpler to setup and use.  `webmin` is probably not the application for your use case.

If you are planning on accessing your files via the Internet and a home based web server, I highly recommend securing the connection via TLS... self-signed certs are fine as long as no one else is connecting to the home server, and you know they were generated by you.

[Superuser: Self-signed certs for home server question](https://superuser.com/questions/1073986/self-signed-certificate-with-openssl-for-server-at-home-and-no-domain-name)

If you have no idea what any of this means... I highly recommend that you don't open your network and home file server up to the Internet.

Comment: God freaking curseword... I've encountered this error while installing Apache.... But owncloud requires PHP and... http://ibb.co/kNY7Cm    This showed up. Why is this happening?!?!

Comment: Also while someone looks at that problem where can I find the files I need to update the permissions to?

Comment: +1 for making clear the negative security implications

Comment: Just to clarify Steve I was never going to make it public to the internet. I was planning on how to encrypt my drive or add a login. And I debated whether or not to port-forward the media server.